# Check if a link contains exact match text

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to find connective words in a string of text and convert them from uppercase to lower case.

I've managed to get it working using this:

```
$(".breadlinks:contains('or')").html(function(_, html) {
    return  html.replace(/(or)/g, '<span class="smallcaps">$1</span>')
});
```

But this will work if the word isn't `or` but it contains `or` like `order`, I only want it to wrap the text in `smallcaps` class if it exact matches.

Here is a link the the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zjfrk3nd/16/

Comment: how to do define exact match? `or` with ` or ` or it can be anything in the left right?

Comment: I just need it to target `or` not `order` as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select element by exact match of its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364298/select-element-by-exact-match-of-its-content)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select the whole text from the link and then do a regex for the "or" like here: [jQuery replacing "small-caps" - Content is Duplicating HTML between <h3> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357173/jquery-replacing-small-caps-content-is-duplicating-html-between-h3-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".breadlinks:contains('Or')").each(function() {
    var updatedHtml = $(this).html().replace(/(?:^|\b)(Or)(?=\b|$)/, '<span class="smallcaps">$1</span>');
    $(this).html(updatedHtml);
});
```